# Elements in a Queue get lost

Tags: python, multithreading, queue

I have a thread with a socket listening for events and putting them into a queue. Then another thread is reading the events and doing something.

Very simplified example follows:

Thread that reads events and queues them:

```
while True:
    event = socket.recv()
    queue.put(event)
```

Thread that reads events:

```
while True:
    event = queue.get()
    queue.task_done()
    #Does something with the event
```

I have several of this programs running in parallel at the same time but they are isolated.

**Problem**:

This events make the program start several processes and they start using CPU. It seems that under high CPU loads something goes wrong: The number of events I put in the queue is bigger than what I get in the second thread.

I tried to debug this everywhere, and it seems that some "events" get lost somewhere, how is this possible? What is going on?

Comment: How do you instantiate queue?

Comment: Queue.Queue(0) its "infinite". Has to be something related to CPU usage, or I do not know what..

Comment: queue.Queue is not porcess safe, it is thread safe, if you need process safe queues use multiprocessing.Queue

Comment: Why would I need a process safe queue? I just have 1 process using that Queue. I just have 2 threads one writing and one reading from it. And then I have multiple processes but each one with its own queue.

Comment: If both threads are in the same process, then thats not the problem, I was miss-understanding your problem.
Are you debugging in a process safe manner?

Comment: I would say so.  Its very strange, because I tried that minimal example with 2000 processes and a putting a lot of events in the queue and it works fine. But then in my normal code for some reason they get lost.

Comment: Can you create a simplified example that actually has the problem?